# Why does Object.assign not copy the properties of a URL object?

Tags: javascript

On macOS **10.13.1** with **Chrome 63**.

I'm using `Object.assign` with [new URL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) as the source object but it always gives an empty object? This seems like strange behavior. Here is my code:

```
 let url = new URL('http://www.yahoo.com');
 console.log(url);
 let data = Object.assign({}, url);
 console.log(data);
```

Why is data an empty object whereas `url` has the complete URL object as below:

```
{
 href: "http://www.yahoo.com/", 
 origin: "http://www.yahoo.com", 
 protocol: "http:", 
 username: "", 
 password: ""
 ...
}
```

I also tried:

```
let data = Object.assign({}, ...url);
```

but it gives:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation for that function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), _"used to copy the values of __all enumerable own__ properties"_

Comment: yes. just checked and find first time what means of that. now my question is how do the copy the property then?

Comment: Which specific properties are you trying to get from the `URL` instance?

Comment: You would need to loop over each of the properties (eg `for...in`), as all the properties are actually getters/setters and based off some internal variable.

Comment: every property I need except `serachParams`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect it's because the properties of `URL` are not `enumerable`. Notice when you do `Object.keys(url)` you also get a blank array? Both `Object.assign` and `Object.keys` work with `enumerable` properties.

Properties on your `url` object are not `enumerable.`

Comment: yes.I have checked `url.propertyIsEnumerable('href')`  which return `false` . so how do the copy the object than?

Comment: @pro.mean You can use a `for in` loop to loop over the properties

Comment: oh, the basic way? not any es6 approach for that?

Comment: @pro.mean `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()`.

Comment: @JaredSmith `Reflect` does not have that method

Comment: @guest271314 yeah just realized, don't know why they copied every static method from `Object` except that one... `Reflect` does have `.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`.

Answer (score 2):

You can clone URL by simply:

```
 let url = new URL('http://www.yahoo.com');
 console.log(url);
 let data = new URL(url);
 console.log(data);
```

URL syntax:

```
url = new URL(url, [base])
```

> You can still use an existing URL object for the base, which
>   stringifies itself to the object's href attribute.